# Simple low pass digital filter implementation for non-uniform sampling?

Tags: low-pass, sampling, digital-filter, random

I have a system sampling an analog input and I want to filter that value using a simple, first order filter.  EG something of the form:

```
Yn = A*Xn + B*Yn-1
```

However I have no control over the underlying process and the sampling period is non-uniform, and varies (randomlyish) somewhere between 25ms and 29ms. In addition I want to use a 30 minute time constant, and can't keep a running buffer of 72,000 sample values.

Given that a typical filter implementation requires a uniform sampling period, is there any simple algorithm that takes into account the time difference between Yn-1 and Xn? (which I guess really means a time varying version of my "constants" A and B)

---

Note that I'm inclined to simply take the average sample time over an extended period and using that to calculate my constants, however there is also the possibility of the final system not running at the same average rate as my test system, so I want to come up with a solution that is  somewhat adaptable.

---

**answering questions**

1. The filtered signal is being used as a part of a vibration monitoring system in some industrial equipment.  It will be used for more of as a qualitative than quantitative purpose.
2. The customer requirements are 30 minute rolling average for the data.
3. I have **zero** control over the sample rate.
4. And the sample rate varies *every* second
5. And the sample rate *defines* the speed at which my code runs
6. The final system should run at about the same speed as my test system, however it could be somewhat slower, maybe down to a 35ms rate

Comment: **1)** What will the filtered signal be used for ? Non uniform sampling of the filtered output may cause problems down the line. **2)** "*In addition I want to use a 30 minute time constant,*" Can you elaborate more on this ? If your system time constant is so slow, do you really need to process the samples with an accuracy of 4 ms ? **3)** Will the average sample time of the final system be fixed / known during operation of the final system ?

Comment: Design a first order *continuous time* filter. Discretise it with sampling period `Ts`, keeping `Ts` as a variable and not a number. `A` and `B` will then be a function of `Ts`. Recalculate `A` and `B` for each sample if you know the `Ts` for that sample.

Comment: S/N ratio improves by \$\sqrt{n}\$ or 10 log n in dB.  Your desired to use a 1st order filter in 1/20 Hz Nyquist BW then  then average it over 1800 samples then make it adaptable to the next average is contradictatory for S/N ratio . Pls  specify  your Noise spectrum and wandering average of final system in measurable terms 1st. Signal spectrum, then noise spectrum. It is better to oversample then use a 2nd order filter than a 6th order Nyquist filter and a 1st order digital filter is NG

Comment: Why don't you iterate/resample between the "flaky" samples to give a much higher rate that your actual flaky sampling can align to. Of course you need your new higher sample rate to be accurate.

Comment: @AJN See updates

Comment: The requirement is clearer now.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I have no control over the sample rates.  And I have no specified requirements for the data you're asking for

Comment: @Andyaka I have no control over teh sample rate and can't oversample.

Comment: Search DSP.SE also for [related questions](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/44804).

Comment: @AJN  Totally missed that there was a DSP.SE  Yet *another* SE to subscribe to

Comment: @PeterM of course you can; if you receive a sample every 27 ms on average then you can resample in the digital domain every 1 ms and this greatly reduces you mistimed real sample to the nearest millisecond. Take it one step further and digitally resample every 0.1 ms then your mistimed samples align with a time spread of 100 microseconds. Would this be accurate enough? I think it would given what you say. But, if not accurate enough, resample digitally every 10 us.

Comment: I didn’t ask for sample rate specs. You ought to consider SNR input spectrum and desired output SNR before designing anything to understand how to reduce error. Analog or SAR + digital filter  or Double integration ADC

Comment: [another one from DSP.SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/24912)

Comment: @Andyaka Umm .. my data arrives at the same rate at which I process it.  I am not and can't run code faster than that rate

Comment: If you have no control over input SNR of signal, then specify what the spectrum looks like and desired or tolerable error. Perhaps a  Gaussian digital filter or matched filter to signal

Comment: Why don't you resample to be uniform and at the same average rate? This can easily be done in realtime and for a few thousand ALU operations per second given your low sampling rate.

Comment: @user1850479 Because I can't do that.  It is inherent in the system I am dealing with.  That is a absolute that cannot be changed.

Comment: With 30 min rolling average and ~35 ms sampling, did you mean that you need 30 min / 35 ms ~ 51429 samples?

Comment: Can't you resample to 25ms (or whatever the final system's rate will be) ?

Comment: @AJN I have absolutely no control over the speed of the sampling, either in my system or in the final system.  Nothing, nada, zilch, zip.    Maybe I need to put that in **32 point bold font**   lol

Comment: Why can't you resample? Could you explain your complete requirements a little more clearly?

Comment: @PeterM So you have a system which works with varying sampling rate. You are basically allowed to write code which will be called by the host system. Your code will be provided with the current input, the time elapsed since last sample, and any variables like previous filter state. You don't have control over how frequently / regularly the host will call your supplied code. Is this correct ?

Comment: @user1850479 I can't resample because my code is running in a free running system that does not execute at a uniform rate.  Instead the cycle time is based on the execution code paths taken at any given time. And the sample time is in lock step with the cycle time.  This is an **absolute constraint** that cannot be changed.

Comment: @ajn that is a close summary.  But basically true

Comment: Yes, you said that before, but why can't you (as part of the low pass filter) compute the uniformly spaced sample values? This is a simple operation that can be done in comparable time just to low pass filtering. If you can't do that then I think low pass filtering will also be impossible, at least from what you have described.

Comment: @user1850479 I think I was thinking of oversampling as a physical rather than a computational operation.  It looks like Andy's answer has set me straight on that

Comment: You don't even need to oversample I think. Just resample to the average rate that samples come in.

Comment: @user1850479 that sounds good but it relies on knowledge that the average becomes recognizably the true average in a reasonably limited space of time (or you might have to hang on to arrays of numbers with no real knowledge that things might settle down). I've probably not worded that very well of course. There may be a simpler way of course because I'm basically an analogue engineer!

Comment: @Andyaka by average I just mean the approximate middle value. What I meant is that there's no reason to oversample, just a simple resample will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say you have no control over the input sampling rate. That is understood but you are not considering the fact that you can resample once inside your digital system AND, I'm presuming you do have control over that else why would you be asking this question. So, resample your digital data like this: -

[image]

Now "real sample" 1 took 25 ms and "real sample" 2 took 29 ms but who cares if you internally resample that data? Yes, you have to process at a much higher rate but it's not like you are having to do major recalculations each time because \$A*X_n\$ is static for 25 to 29 samples.

Comment: except that my code runs at the same speed as the sample rate.  Or another way the sample rate is same speed as my code execution rate.  I can't process data faster than the sample rate.

Comment: Hmm .. however I could pretend that I run the code at a faster rate.  EG design for a 1 ms rate and run X iterations at each code execution point, where X is the time between samples

Comment: But you can execute hundreds (if not thousands) of lines of code at a much higher rate than the incoming flaky sample rate.

Comment: I can only run code at the sample rate. They are in lock step

Comment: OK we're taking about the same thing I think

Comment: How many lines of code can you execute in 25 ms @PeterM

Comment: I don't have the specs handy, but more than enough to even out the sampling to make it pretend sampling at a higher speed.  I'm going to call that pseudo oversampling

Comment: It's actually called digital over-sampling and is a recognized thing.

Comment: Now I know.  It's been a really long time since I've had to work in this area so I am not familiar with the terminology.  But it looks like that is the solution to my problem

Answer (score 3):

Consider the first order continuous time filter \$\frac{dy(t)}{dt} = -k y(t) + k x(t)\$

One of the many choices to discretise the above filter is

$$\frac{y_{(t)}-y_{(t-T_s)}}{Ts} = -k y_{(t-T_s)} + k x_{(t)}$$
$$ y_{(t)} = k\cdot T_s x_{(t)} + (1 - k\cdot T_s)y_{(t- T_s)}$$

`A` and `B` to be used for each sample can be found from above expression.

The above is only an ad-hoc method. There may be proper algorithms for variable sampling rate filtering available in lierature with well defined mathematical properties.

[A suggestion](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/24912) from From DSP.SE

> Remember that filters are dynamical systems and solve the corresponding ordinary differential equation (ODE)
> In the second method, you basically use the retrieved time step as the time step in the ODE solver. Assuming you have a second order system:

Answer (score 1):

Here comes the math. Let me assume, your low pass filter has a time constant \$\tau\$. It takes amplitude inputs values \$a_n\$ at points in time \$t_n\$ and it shall produce ouptut values \$b_n\$ for the same points in time. The starting condition is \$a_0 = 0\$ at \$t_0 = 0\$. So I initialize

\$b_0 = 0\$

All further output values can be computed as a weighted average of the previous output and the current input.

\$b_n = w_n a_n + (1-w_n) b_{n-1}\$

The weights \$w_n\$ can be computed from the well known low pass repsonse in time to the unit step function.

\$w_n = 1 - exp(\frac{-\Delta t_n}{\tau} )\$

where

\$\Delta t_n = t_n - t_{n-1}\$

So that is basically it. Here comes an example with \$\tau = 32\$. I have used a far higher non-uniformity for the sampling period as in the given question to make the effects more visible.

[image]

When working on a restricted processor such as a tiny microcontroller, calculating the weights nonlinearily as \$w_n = 1 - exp(-\Delta t_n / \tau)\$ may be costly. In those cases a linear approximation may serve well.

\$w_n \approx min(1, \frac{\Delta t_n}{\tau})\$

I tried it with the depicted example and the results cannot be distinguished visually.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to do what you ask for exactly... but you don't really need to do that.  A 30 minute running average will erase all of your hard work.

Start by converting to a regular 1-second sampling rate just by taking the average of all the sample values within each second.

Then apply regular-sampling methods on the result.

Comment: What you are suggesting is basically what AJN suggests.  However in your case you are suggesting converting the data into 1 second blocks vs oversampling in order to treat the data as 1ms samples.  Programmatically both approaches will end up having a similar amount of instructions.  Computationally your approach *could* be more efficient, but that isn't a concern in my system.  Numerically your approach may require variables of a smaller bit width, but again I have sufficient overhead that I can absorb AJNs approach.  And finally I've already implemented it and I'm not redoing it! LOL

Comment: lol at "could" :). I'm sure your time is more valuable than the CPU you would save, but oversampling by 30 times in order to decimate by 60000 will get you disapproving glances at all the DSP parties.

Comment: The task was implemented in a manner that works. However my time has a dollar cost associated with it, and with all the other tasks performed on that project the purchase order was totally drained.  So arbitrarily changing one working methodology to another one would mean working without a PO - effectively working for free.  That is something I only do when there is a really compelling reason, and this doesn't even come close.  And I also don't go to those sorts of parties :P